# Putting people into a group based on their indices

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that there are $984$ people numbered $1,\ldots,984$. Of these people, we are to pick $n$ people such that:

- We know that person number $12$ is picked
- If person number $x$ is picked, and person number $y$ is *not* picked, then if $x \cdot y \le 984$, person number $x \cdot y$ is picked
- If person number $x$ is picked, and person number $y$ is *not* picked, then if $x + y \le 984$, person number $x + y$ is *not* picked

How many people are we going to pick (what is the value of $n$)? I tried solving this by brute force with a simple C program and got $n = 82$. However, I am absolutely clueless when it comes to a mathematical solution (in other words, I have no means to verify my result). So please, enlighten me a bit.

Comment: As it stands you can pick them all - the final two conditions are then redundant (never apply), while the first is obviously satisfied.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit further? My brute force approach was by selecting the people based on $x \cdot y$ and deselecting them based on $x + y$.

Comment: If everyone is picked, then we never have a pair where $x$ is picked and $y$ is not - for every pair both $x$ and $y$ are picked and there no reason we can't pick $x+y$ and $x\cdot y$, because the last two conditions do not apply.

Comment: Hey, I must be blind to have missed that. Good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions. I will assume that one picks $12$ and then goes through with the logical consequences from the second and third condition while picking the fewest number of people.

All multiples of $12$ are chosen after the initial pick of $12$. We can stop there, since $12n\cdot y = 12 n'$; in other words, multiples of $12$ yield only multiples of $12$. It is similarly easy to see that this strategy does not violate condition three.

Notice that $984/12 = 82$.

We can also pick $983$ without any violations. Similarly with many more numbers.

Subtlety: $144$ is not picked immediately from condition two. But if $144$ is not picked, then $144 + 12 = 156 = 12\cdot 13$ is not picked, a violation (unless we pick $13$). Similarly with any multiple of $144$. (Since every multiple of $144$ is more than $12$ less than $984$, we can use this strategy for all of them.)